# Firefox User Agent Switcher - how do I get to it?

Tags: firefox, user-agent

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

I've installed it in Firefox, but, how do I actually *get* to it?  I don't see it in my toolbar, I don't see if it I right click anywhere close to my toolbar.  It's not one of the Chrome-looking extension buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Right click your navigation toolbar and click "Customize", then scroll down and 
find User Agent Switcher icon. You can drag&drop it to your navigation toolbar.

You can start using it this way.

Comment: for me this is the right answer. The User Agent switcher icon isn't displayed by default...

Answer (score 0):

Underneath tools you should see a "Default User Agent" drop down.  Roll over this menu item and you should see alternative User Agents.  Screenshot @ http://www.bemoko.com/training/help/product/useragent-switcher including an import file with a good collection of mobile user agents (nicely organised and annotated with screen dimensions)